# Is possible to schedule a method to run everyday?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I have a service with only one method inside. I would like to schedule this method to run everyday at 01:00am. Can I do this using only IBM Integration Bus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [TimeoutNotification Node](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac20802_.htm) in IBM Integration Bus.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you should be able to do it quite eazily using timer nodes available in IIB. The  timeout control and timeout notification nodes permit you to schedule reccuring events or time based events. The [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0603_schutz/0603_schutz-pdf.pdf) is slightly old , but gives a really good idea of going about this.